# Remove all whitespace in a string

Tags: python, string, trim, removing-whitespace

I want to eliminate all the whitespace from a string, on both ends, and in between words.

I have this Python code:

```py
def my_handle(self):
    sentence = ' hello  apple  '
    sentence.strip()
```

But that only eliminates the whitespace on both sides of the string. How do I remove all whitespace?

Comment: What should your result look like? `hello apple`? `helloapple`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, not exactly I think, because it's also about reducung whitespace between the words.

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but "whitespace" is not synonymous with "space characters". The current answer marked as correct does not remove all [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). But, since it's marked as correct it must have answered the intended question? So we should edit the question to reflect the accepted answer? @Kalanamith Did, or do, you want to remove all whitespace or only spaces?

Answer (score 2324, accepted):

If you want to remove leading and ending spaces, use [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> "  hello  apple  ".strip()
'hello  apple'
```

If you want to remove all space characters, use [`str.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) *(NB this only removes the “normal” ASCII space character `' ' U+0020` but not [any other whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode))*:

```
>>> "  hello  apple  ".replace(" ", "")
'helloapple'
```

If you want to remove duplicated spaces, use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) followed by `str.join()`:

```
>>> " ".join("  hello  apple  ".split())
'hello apple'
```

Comment: The greatness of this function is that it also removes the '\r\n' from the html file I received from Beautiful Soup.

Comment: I like "".join(sentence.split()), this removes all whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) from anywhere in sentence.

Comment: begginner here. Can someone explain me why print(sentence.join(sentence.split())) results to 'hello hello appleapple'? Just want to understand how code is processed here.

Comment: @YannisDran check the [str.join() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), when you call `sentence.join(str_list)` you ask python to join items from str_list with `sentence`as separator.

Comment: `"".join(sentence.split())` is indeed the canonical solution, efficiently removing *all* whitespace rather than merely spaces. [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers)' [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270124/2809027) should probably have been accepted in lieu of this less applicable answer.

Comment: in case of more than 2 whitespaces in the end  string, extra `sentence.strip().rstrip()` can help
same goes for `sentence.strip().lstrip()` for beginnig.
Not perfect, but works without the need for `re`

that's in case simple `.strip()` misses them

Comment: The solution works but is slightly confusing - when using replace, it returns the string, and doesn't replace in-place, so you need `sentence = sentence.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: Agree with @CecilCurry If the string can be anything and the intention is to replace all whitespaces, it should be ` "".join(sentence.split()) `

Answer (score 431):

To remove *only spaces* use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
sentence = sentence.replace(' ', '')
```

To remove *all whitespace characters* (space, tab, newline, and so on) you can use [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) then [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
sentence = ''.join(sentence.split())
```

or a regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
sentence = re.sub(pattern, '', sentence)
```

If you want to only remove whitespace from the beginning and end you can use [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
sentence = sentence.strip()
```

You can also use [`lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) to remove whitespace only from the beginning of the string, and [`rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove whitespace from the end of the string.

Comment: Note: You don't need to compile step, re.sub (and friends) cache the compiled pattern. See also, [Emil's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28607213/1240268).

Comment: python3: `yourstr.translate(str.maketrans('', '', ' \n\t\r'))`

Answer (score 160):

An alternative is to use regular expressions and match [these strange white-space characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) too. Here are some examples:

**Remove ALL spaces in a string, even between words:**

```
import re
sentence = re.sub(r"\s+", "", sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

**Remove spaces in the BEGINNING of a string:**

```
import re
sentence = re.sub(r"^\s+", "", sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

**Remove spaces in the END of a string:**

```
import re
sentence = re.sub(r"\s+$", "", sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

**Remove spaces both in the BEGINNING and in the END of a string:**

```
import re
sentence = re.sub("^\s+|\s+$", "", sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

**Remove ONLY DUPLICATE spaces:**

```
import re
sentence = " ".join(re.split("\s+", sentence, flags=re.UNICODE))
```

(All examples work in both Python 2 and Python 3)

Comment: Did not work for "\u202a1234\u202c". Gives the same output:  u'\u202a1234\u202c'

Comment: @Sarang: Those are not whitespace characters (google them and you'll see) but "General Punctuation". My answer only deals with removing characters classified as whitespace.

Comment: This is the only solution I see here that removes those damn pesky unicode whitespace characters, thanks fam

Answer (score 65):

"Whitespace" includes **space, tabs, and CRLF**. So an elegant and **one-liner** string function we can use is [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

Python 3

```
' hello  apple '.translate(str.maketrans('', '', ' \n\t\r'))
```

**OR** if you want to be thorough:

```
import string
' hello  apple'.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.whitespace))
```

Python 2

```
' hello  apple'.translate(None, ' \n\t\r')
```

**OR** if you want to be thorough:

```
import string
' hello  apple'.translate(None, string.whitespace)
```

Comment: This won't help with Unicode whitespace like `\xc2\xa0`

Comment: `ans.translate( None, string.whitespace )` produces only `builtins.TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)` for me. Docs says that argument is a translate table, see string.maketrans(). But see comment by Amnon Harel, below.

Comment: `' hello  apple'.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.whitespace))`
Note: its better to make a variable to store the trans-table if you intend to do this multiple times.

Answer (score 20):

For removing whitespace from beginning and end, use `strip`.

```
>> "  foo bar   ".strip()
"foo bar"
```

Comment: The question specifically asks for removing all of the whitespace and not just at the ends. Please take notice.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to this question

Answer (score 13):

```
' hello  \n\tapple'.translate({ord(c):None for c in ' \n\t\r'})
```

MaK already pointed out the "translate" method above. And this variation works with Python 3 (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038891/what-does-table-in-the-string-translate-function-mean)).

Comment: Thanks! Or, `xxx.translate( { ord(c) :None for c in string.whitespace } )` for thoroughness.

Answer (score 11):

In addition, [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) has some variations:

**Remove spaces in the BEGINNING and END of a string:**

```
sentence= sentence.strip()
```

**Remove spaces in the BEGINNING of a string:**

```
sentence = sentence.lstrip()
```

**Remove spaces in the END of a string:**

```
sentence= sentence.rstrip()
```

All three string functions `strip` `lstrip`, and `rstrip` can take parameters of the string to strip, with the default being all white space. This can be helpful when you are working with something particular, for example, you could remove only spaces but not newlines:

```
" 1. Step 1\n".strip(" ")
```

Or you could remove extra commas when reading in a string list:

```
"1,2,3,".strip(",")
```

Answer (score 7):

Be careful:

`strip` does a rstrip and lstrip (removes leading and trailing spaces, tabs, returns and form feeds, but it does not remove them in the middle of the string).

If you only replace spaces and tabs you can end up with hidden CRLFs that appear to match what you are looking for, but are not the same.

Comment: Although this is a good point, this isn't really an answer and should be a comment unless you provide a solution. Would you care to provide a solution for this is exactly what I'm looking for? Cheers

Answer (score 6):

> eliminate all the whitespace from a string, on both ends, and in between words.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("\s+", # one or more repetition of whitespace
    '', # replace with empty string (->remove)
    ''' hello
...    apple
... ''')
'helloapple'
```

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Python docs:

- https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#textseq
- https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace
- https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace
- https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub
- https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: I know `re` has been suggested before, but I found that the actual answer to the question title was a bit hidden amongst all the other options.

Answer (score 5):

I use split() to ignore all whitespaces and use join() to concatenate
strings.

```py
sentence = ''.join(' hello  apple  '.split())
print(sentence) #=> 'helloapple'
```

I prefer this approach because it is only a expression (not a statement).
It is easy to use and it can use without binding to a variable.

```py
print(''.join(' hello  apple  '.split())) # no need to binding to a variable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import re    
sentence = ' hello  apple'
re.sub(' ','',sentence) #helloworld (remove all spaces)
re.sub('  ',' ',sentence) #hello world (remove double spaces)
```

Comment: the question was too remove all white space which includes tabs and new line characters, this snippet will only remove regular spaces.

Answer (score 3):

In the following script we import the regular expression module which we use to substitute one space or more with a single space. This ensures that the inner extra spaces are removed. Then we use strip() function to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
# Import regular expression module
import re

# Initialize string
a = "     foo      bar   "

# First replace any number of spaces with a single space
a = re.sub(' +', ' ', a)

# Then strip any leading and trailing spaces.
a = a.strip()

# Show results
print(a)
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the recommendation I just added the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works the best for me:

```
test_string = '  test   a   s   test '
string_list = [s.strip() for s in str(test_string).split()]
final_string = ' '.join(string_array)
# final_string: 'test a s test'
```

It removes any whitespaces, tabs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All string characters are unicode literal in Python 3; as a consequence, since `str.split()` splits on *all* white space characters, that means it splits on unicode white space characters. So `split` + `join` syntax (as in
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270146/19123103),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270124/19123103),
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68577881/19123103)) will produce the same output as `re.sub` with the UNICODE flag (as in [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28607213/19123103)); in fact, the UNICODE flag is redundant here (as in
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270124/19123103),
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71184358/19123103),
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60673521/19123103),
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40218832/19123103)).

```py
import re
import sys

# all unicode characters
sentence = ''.join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)))

# remove all white space characters
x = ''.join(sentence.split())
y = re.sub(r"\s+", "", sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
z = re.sub(r"\s+", "", sentence)

x == y == z      # True
```

In terms of performance, since Python's string methods are optimized, they are much faster than regex. As the following timeit test shows, when removing all white space characters from the string in the OP, Python string methods are over 7 times faster than `re` option.

```py
import timeit

import timeit

setup = """
import re
s = ' hello  \t apple  '
"""

t1 = min(timeit.repeat("''.join(s.split())", setup))
t2 = min(timeit.repeat("re.sub(r'\s+', '', s, flags=re.UNICODE)", setup))


t2 / t1  # 7.868004799367726
```

Answer (score -2):

try this.. instead of using re i think using split with strip is much better

```
def my_handle(self):
    sentence = ' hello  apple  '
    ' '.join(x.strip() for x in sentence.split())
#hello apple
    ''.join(x.strip() for x in sentence.split())
#helloapple
```