# Reverse each word in a string

Tags: python, string

I am having a small problem in my code. I am trying to reverse the words and the character of a string. For example "the dog ran" would become "ehT god nar"

The code almost works. It just does not add spaces. How would you do that?

```
def reverseEachWord(str):
  reverseWord=""
  list=str.split()
  for word in list:
    word=word[::-1]
    reverseWord=reverseWord+word+""
  return reverseWord
```

Comment: "The code almost works. It just does not add spaces. How would you do that? " It's a little confusing to me how the question could have been asked. Where the original code says `reverseWord=reverseWord+word+""` - one has to wonder, what was the intended purpose of the `+""` part? Did OP try using anything else there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are on the right track. The main issue is that `""` is an empty string, not a space (and even if you fix this, you probably don't want a space after the final word).

Here is how you can do this more concisely:

```
>>> s='The dog ran'
>>> ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in s.split())
'ehT god nar'
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the sentence has two spaces between the words.

Answer (score 4):

```
def reversed_words(sequence):
    return ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in sequence.split())

>>> s = "The dog ran"
>>> reversed_words(s)
... 'ehT god nar'
```

Comment: Ha. virtually identical to @aix. Beaten to it.

Comment: And it doesn't work for a sentence with two spaces between words as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
name=input('Enter first and last name:')
for n in name.split():
    print(n[::-1],end=' ')
```

Comment: In general "code only" answers are considered to be bad practice. Please open up a little bit what your code does and how it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also deal with noise in the string using the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "The \n\tdog \t\nran"
>>> " ".join(w[::-1] for w in re.split(r"\s+", s))
'ehT god nar'
```

Or if you don't care:

```
>>> s = "The dog ran"
>>> re.sub(r"\w+", lambda w: w.group(0)[len(w.group(0))::-1], s)
'Teh god nar'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse_words(sentence):        
     return " ".join((lambda x : [i[::-1] for i in x])(sentence.split(" ")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about it is by adding a space to your words `reverseWord=reverseWord+word+" "` and removing the space at the end of your output by using `.strip()`

```
def reverse_words(str):
  reverseWord = ""
  list = str.split()
  for word in list:
    word = word[::-1]
    reverseWord = reverseWord + word + " "
  return reverseWord.strip()
```

check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string) on how it's used

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using join / split :

```
def reverse(sentence):
    answer = ''
    temp = ''
    for char in sentence:
        if char != ' ':
            temp += char
            continue
        rev = ''
        for i in range(len(temp)):
            rev += temp[len(temp)-i-1]
        answer += rev + ' '
        temp = ''
    return answer + temp
reverse("This is a string to try")
```

Answer (score 0):

A version without Python-level looping and with reversing the whole string once instead of each word separately.

```py
def reverseEachWord(s):
    return " ".join(s[::-1].split()[::-1])

print(reverseEachWord("the dog ran"))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3M1NS0xSKUstSi4pTXROTM8Lzi1I0ijWtuBSAoCi1pLQoT0FJQUkvKz8zT6M42spK1zBWr7ggJ7NEQxPC0-TiKijKzCvRQDdFqSQjVSElP12hKDFPSVMTYiHUXpj9AA)

Benchmark with the top answer's solution:

```
With s = 'The dog ran':
2.30 μs  ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in s.split())
0.72 μs  " ".join(s[::-1].split()[::-1])

With s = 'The dog ran' * 1000:
458 μs  ' '.join(w[::-1] for w in s.split())
185 μs  " ".join(s[::-1].split()[::-1])
```

Benchmark script:

```py
from timeit import repeat

codes = [
    "' '.join(w[::-1] for w in s.split())",
    '" ".join(s[::-1].split()[::-1])',
]

for code in codes:
    t = min(repeat(code, "s = 'The dog ran'", number=10**5))
    print(f'{t*1e1:4.2f} μs ', code)

print()

for code in codes:
    t = min(repeat(code, "s = 'The dog ran' * 1000", number=10**2))
    print(f'{t*1e4:3.0f} μs ', code)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZFNTkMhFEbjlFXcMOHxQl-g1sSQdBedNR1UCxYjPwGal8a4Eied6CpcgwtwNT7ADjTOyoxwPs6Xe1_fwzHvvTud3g5Zz26_rkYdvYVsrDIZjA0-ZogqqG1G6N7vVIIlrBFMBxMgw6M3rhvXUs7EBrSPMIJxkIYUnkzuKMWssgQDbmxq7BloN0oY2iBU8sVRvqguWcN5Utop2mp05YUBLkXIaq9g5x8gbh3BDNzB3qm4FLzvbyit4RCNy50mz7kXSsjFMNcv8PmRgLDqoAg1hF7qhx4E5_x3jfl_NRbyeuB_arT5_6zhvI5v)