# Cannot convert string to int in Python

Tags: python, arrays, hash, sum, type-conversion

What's wrong with this python snippet:

```
for zhszam in pontok.keys():
    s = 0
    for p in pontok[zhszam]:
        if p.isdigit():
            s += int(p)
            print s
    pontok[zhszam] = s
return pontok
```

where *pontok* is `{1: ['10', ' 5', ' 3', ' 10', ' 7'], 2: ['10', ' 5', ' 3', ' 10']}`.
It gives the following wrong output somehow:

```
10
10
{1: 10, 2: 10}
```

While the values should be the sum of the numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: indentation as a start...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every string except the first `'10'` has a leading space, which isn't a digit. Thus it's not being processed at all.

Try:

```
for p in pontok[zhszam]:
    p = p.strip()
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `str.isdigit`, it can break very easily. Better use a try-except block with `int()`.

```
>>> dic = {1: ['10', ' 5', ' 3', ' 10', ' 7'], 2: ['10', ' 5', ' 3', ' 10']}
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    s = 0
    for x in v:
        try:
            s += int(x)     #raises Error if the item is not a valid number
        except:              
            pass            #leave the item as it is if an error was thrown
    dic[k] = s 
...     
>>> dic
{1: 35, 2: 28}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather comment than leave this as an answer, but I haven't the rep yet. This question will help you with stripping those leading spaces: [Python remove all whitespace in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-whitespaces-in-string)