# Remove whitespace from a string

Tags: python

How can I convert the string (s) into required string (ans)? This is simple string manipulation in python.

```
s = '(107, 163, 138, 255)'


ans = '(107,163,138,255)'
```

Comment: use `ans = s.replace(" ","")`

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string). Here you can find different methods to remove spaces in different places / complete removal of spaces of a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the replace method to replace the whitespace with nothing:

```
>>> s = '(107, 163, 138, 255)'
>>> s.replace(" ", "")
'(107,163,138,255)'
```