# python3 remove space from print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got some simple python loop through a name to create a list of devices:

```
for i in range(18):
print("sfo-router",(i))
```

The problem is it prints with a space between the name and the number:

```
sforouter 1
sforouter 2
sforouter 3
sforouter 4
```

I'm just learning the ropes of python, so not sure how I can remove that space.
How can it be done?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `sep` parameter so that `print` doesn't implicitly insert a space:

```
for i in range(18):
    print("sfo-router",(i), sep='')
```

Alternatively, you can convert your number to a string with `str` and concatenate:

```
for i in range(18):
    print("sfo-router" + str(i))
```

**Outputs: (*in both cases*)**

```
sfo-router0
sfo-router1
sfo-router2
sfo-router3
sfo-router4
sfo-router5
...
```

Comment: Thanks guys, all those methods work well. Can you help me understand why the space is there in the first place?

Comment: Because the default separator is a space in this case!

Answer (score 2):

Use format:

```
for i in range(18):
    print("sfo-router{}".format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at python as well, and a quick google search did this one:

Just use `str.replace()`:

```
string = 'hey man'
string.replace(" ","")
# String is now 'heyman'
```

Source: [Python remove all whitespace in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string)

Comment: You can avoid constructing the string with any spaces, so you shouldn't need to remove them.

Comment: sorry, i'm new at python as well, this seemed like an easy solution, will try better next time!

Comment: It is all good, and an excellent way to get better at python is trying to answer some questions.