# Get rid of spaces or join

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to read this as a palindrome, backward, it works within one word with no spaces but doesn't with `Taco Cat`.

How do I join or get rid of spaces?

```
def is_palindrome():
    string = input("Enter a palindrome: ")
    string = string.lower()
    string = string.whitespace()
    rev_str = reversed(string)
    if list(string) == list(rev_str):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

is_palindrome()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python remove all whitespace in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string)

Comment: I tried the does not work

Comment: Which specifically did you try?  Also... string.whitespace looks like it should be a string of whitespace, so I don't see how string.whitespace() does anything besides throw an exception that you can't call a string.  (https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html)

Comment: tried strip(), .replace() etc

Comment: string = string.replace(' ','') works just fine for my test using "Taco Cat"

Comment: although one word works perfectly

Comment: The `string = string.replace(' ', '')` solution *does* work; if it isn't working for you, you're making another mistake somewhere. Try *replacing* your incorrect `string = string.whitespace()` call with that `string = string.replace(' ', '')` line, not just adding it to your existing code.

Comment: Just did still not working

Comment: "still not working" tells us nothing about how to help you. WHAT is not working? What error message do you get? What results do you get, and how do they differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: there is no error met, its converts to lover case, but not joining words

Comment: Enter a palindrome: ksk ksk
ksk ksk

Comment: Because I just did *exactly* what I suggested you do (replace the `string.whitespace()` call with `string.replace(' ', '')` in your code) and it DOES work (it identified "Taco Cat" as a palindrome). So you're doing something else wrong, but we can't figure out what unless you give us more details.

Comment: I just entered "ksk ksk ksk ksk" (without the quotes) and got "True".

Answer (score 1):

`string = string.replace(' ', '')` can works fine here:

```
def is_palindrome():
    string = str(input("Enter a palindrome: "))
    string = string.lower()
    string = string.replace(' ', '')
    rev_str = reversed(string)
    if list(string) == list(rev_str):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

is_palindrome()
```

Demo:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ python test.py 
Enter a palindrome: Taco Cat
True
[user@localhost ~]$
```

You also can try put a `print(string)` after `string = string.replace(' ', '')` and see what's the output. However I got `tacocat`.