# Python - How to make one input correspond to several functions

Tags: python

My program should have a single input where you write either an arabic number, a roman number, or adding roman numbers. For example:

```
Year: 2001
... MMI

Year: LX
... 60

Year: MI + CI + I
... MCIII

Year: ABC
... That's not a correct roman numeral
```

Well, I guess you get the deal. First, I tried with something like this:

```
def main():


    year = input ("Year: ")


    if type(int(year)) == type(1):
        arab_to_rome(year)

    else:
        rome_to_arab(year)
main()
```

This have obvious problems, firstly, everything else than an integer will be considered as roman numerals and it doesn't take addition in consideration.

Then I googled and found something called isinstance. This is the result of trying that:

```
def main(input):

    year = input ("Year: ")


    if isinstance(input,int):
        arab_to_rome(year)

    elif isinstance(input,str):
        rome_to_arab (year)
    else:
        print ("Error")
main()
```

This has problems as well. I get an error message stating: `Invalid syntax.`
 This code doesn't take addition in consideration either.

Comment: Please write your code into the question so that we can copy it to work with it.

Comment: consider applying `.split("+")` to your input string to detect additions and isolate the terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a try/except block to see if the input is an `int`. This makes up the first 3 lines of the code. For more on that see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number) question.

```
year = input('Year: ')
try:
   print(arab_to_rome(int(year)))
except ValueError:
   result = 0
   for numeral in year.split('+'):
       numeral.replace(' ','')
       result += rome_to_arab(numeral)
   print(result)
```

The part after the `except` is a simple way to handle the addition, and you could migrate this into your `rome_to_arab` function if you wish. It splits the string on each `+` and then add the result of the Arabic calculations together to make a complete Arabic result. The `replace()` function gets rid of any extra spaces to make sure it doesn't break your other methods. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string) question or more info on `split()` and `replace()`.

As you haven't shown us the conversion methods I'm going to assume `arab_to_rome` returns a `string` and `rome_to_arab` returns an `int`. If not you should probably change them such that they do (not just for my example, but for good code convention)