# Palindrome sentence, how to ignore the punctuation

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
word = input("Enter a word:")
a = word[::-1]
print (a)

if a == word:
    print ("The entered word is a palindrome.")
if a != word:
    print ("The entered word is not a palindrome.")
```

This is my current code to see if a word is a palindrome or not.
A palindrome is a word that is written the same backwards/forwards. e.g mum and dad, hannah etc.

How would I change this so that I can use it for a phrase also? 
e.g a phrase could be : 
"Lisa Bonet ate no basil"

However, with the code I have it wouldn't recognise the sentence as a palindrome. What do I need to do to fix that?

Comment: Remove punctuation and whitespace from `word`?

Comment: if I used the sentence "sit on a potato pan otis" the program still says it isn't a palindrome

Comment: You're looking at removing spaces, not punctuation, although the effect would be the same. This is a common programming problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.punctuation`:

```
import string
p = string.punctuation
s = "Lisa Bonet ate no basil"
word = ''.join([x for x in s.lower() if not x in p]).replace(' ','') ## 'lisabonetatenobasil'

## Your logic here
```

You want to remove all the whitespace (hence `.replace(' ','')`) and you also want to standardize case (hence `.lower()`) for palindromes.