# Remove spaces before newlines

Tags: python

I need to remove all spaces before the newline character throughout a string.

```
string = """
this is a line       \n
this is another           \n
"""
```

output:

```
string = """
this is a line\n
this is another\n
"""
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *split* the string into lines, *strip* off all whitespaces on the right using `rstrip`, then add a new line at the end of each line:

```
''.join([line.rstrip()+'\n' for line in string.splitlines()])
```

Comment: If the string doesn't end with a newline, this will add one (which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: @ekhumoro Good observation. One could use this approach on a slice of the splitted lines that excludes the last and treat the last one differently. Depends on OP.

Comment: It works but leaves a newline at the end of the string like what ekhumoro said. so, I use use rstrip() to remove that newline. works fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
re.sub('\s+\n','\n',string)
```

Edit: better version from comments:

```
re.sub(r'\s+$', '', string, flags=re.M)
```

Comment: This will fail for lines which don't end with a newline. Better to use `re.sub(r'\s+$', '', string, flags=re.M)`.

Answer (score -1):

As you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string),

To remove all whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, and so on) you can use split then join:

```
sentence = ''.join(sentence.split())
```

or a regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
sentence = re.sub(pattern, '', sentence)
```

Comment: But he don't want to replace all whitespaces.

Comment: That you'r talking about is `str.replace()` not `str.sub()`

Comment: OP doesn't want to remove all the whitespace in the string, only at the ends of lines. Your solution removes all the spaces, even between words in a sentence.