# How to remove spaces from lists in lists [python]

Tags: python, list, file, split, integer

The file contains:

```
3
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

output: `[[3],[7,4],[2,4,6],[8,5,9,3]]`

my output:

```
 [[3], [7, 4], [2, 4, 6], [8, 5, 9, 3]]    
      ^       ^          ^             // don't want these spaces
```

my solution:

```
def read_triangle(filename):
    f = open(filename,'r')
    triangle = []
    for line in f:
        splited = line.split()
        triangle.append([])
        for num in splited:
            triangle[-1].append(int(num))           
    f.close()
    return triangle
```

what do i have to do to remove spaces?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: my output: [[3], [7, 4], [2, 4, 6] : (there is a space between each index and inside the index it self. but the output must be without any space.

Comment: It's exactly the same list. Are you absolutely sure you're required to print it all scrunched up like that?

Comment: How are you printing the list? Are you using `print(read_triangle(filename))`

Comment: @HalaTwin This has nothing to do with the list itself. It had everything to do with how it's printed by default.

Comment: Could you show how you output the list to the file? `list`s in Python should not randomly space their output.

Comment: its a function. Im not using print(read_triangle(filename))

Comment: @HalaTwin How are you printing the list though? Are you using `print`? Or are you evaluating it in a REPL?

Comment: The correct out put and my output are not the same, My out put contains spaces, and i need to get rid of them . i just can figute out how, i tried a lot of thing but it doesnt work.

Comment: @PavneetSingh - It has nothing to do with `split()`.

Comment: @HalaTwin You need to provide us an [MCVE]. It's completely unclear as to how you are printing a list. If you are using the REPL directly and calling the function, then use `.replace` method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string. Voting to close the post as unclear

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 not sure but i have used split and did give me these spaces in output when input number series had no spaces

Comment: @PavneetSingh You used `split(' ')` and not `split()`.

Comment: @BhargavRao yeah you are right , i used 'split(',')' , seems like something subtle issue

Answer (score 1):

Your output is fine. You have the correct list. The required output only appears without spaces because whoever typed it was too lazy to hit the spacebar (I'm guilty of that from time to time, as well). You could get that output with `str(result).replace(' ', '')`, but, again, it is not necessary. The Python interpreter's default representation of a list object simply includes spaces for readability.

Nothing is wrong.

Comment: I tried str(result).replace(' ', ''), but still didn't work cuz I have a list in a list .

Comment: @HalaTwin - `result = [[3],[7,4],[2,4,6],[8,5,9,3]]; str(result).replace(' ', '')` produces `'[[3],[7,4],[2,4,6],[8,5,9,3]]'` for me.

Comment: I keep getting this Error:
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\python.py", line 11, in read_triangle
    return str(result.replace(' ',''))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: seems like wired OP requirement , agree user don't need it , 1

Comment: @HalaTwin - You are misplacing the parentheses. Reread and try again.