# string == not working

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

This was working a few minutes ago but now I can't get it to work at all.

```
for i in range(0, len(find)):
    for j in range(0, len(X)):
        print(find[i], X[j])
        if find[i] == X[j]:
            longitude.append(float(lon[j]));
            latitude.append(float(lat[j]));

print(len(longitude))

LS5  LS6
LS5  LS7
LS5  LS6
LS5  LS7
LS6  LS6
...
0
```

for some reason its clearly equal but doesn't go through the if statement. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: did you check white space?

Comment: most probably you have extra whitespaces, try `print('"{}"'.format(find[i]), '"{}"'.format(X[j]))`.

Comment: Two objects can have the same *apparent* string representation without being equal. What's the output of `print(repr(find[i]), repr(X[j]))`?

Comment: Can you fill this in a bit so that others can reproduce the problem? (What are `find`, `X`, `lon`, and `lat`?)

Comment: I did the print and it returns: "LS8 " "LS7" it seems that find file has a tab after, any idea how i can remove this whitespace?

Comment: Use `str.strip` to remove whitespaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all whitespace in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: adding .rstrip()  has removed the whitespace on the right and is now working. thank you guys