# Having trouble updating python input into lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, lowercase

So I am trying to create a program that takes in a customer choice of food. I want the user to be able to input their choice in capitals so I can then convert it to lowercase and then compare it using an if statement

```
Name = str(input("What is your Name?"))
Name = ''.join(Name.split())
foodChoice = str(input("Would you like a Burger or Salad?"))
foodChoice = foodChoice.lower()

if foodChoice == 'burger':
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Let's assume the customer inputs "BurgER"

The problem I'm experience is that even after I convert "BurgER" into lowercase after the input is declared, the if statement still regards it as false...take a look at my sample output below

What is your name? *Jason*

Would you like a Burger or Salad? *Burger*

*false*

*Process finished with exit code 0*

**EDIT: The problem seemed to be because I added a space before burger out of habit :/, on that note, is there any way to account for this?**

Comment: This code works perfectly. Can you show us the input and output that seems to cause problem?

Comment: Hey Oliver, I edited my output above in my post to display my problem.

Comment: Your code works for me too, and I can't get your output. Are not you putting a whitespace unintentionally?

Comment: I think you're right Diogo, I add a space before I put my input. Is there any way to account for this?

Comment: @CosmicCat posted as an answer.

Comment: On some os, input get the linebreak, you might want to us strip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your output, the problem is that you added a whitespace before your input which made the statement evaluates to false.

To avoid this, I advise you to use the [`strip`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) function, thus removing the spaces at the beginning and end of the string.

So, in your case, it would be:

```
foodChoice = foodChoice.lower().strip()
```

Additionally, you could use `rstrip()` to only remove whitespaces on the right side of the string, and `lstrip()` to whitespaces on the left side.

Comment: could foodChoice =' '.join(foodChoice.split()).lower() also work?

Comment: It will, because split() transforms consecutive whitespace in a single whitespace, and removes leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the strip method which removes whitespace from the beginning and the end of the string.

Change

```
foodChoice = foodChoice.lower()
```

To

```
foodChoice = foodChoice.lower().strip()
```

More info can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string-in-python).