# How can I output a string excluding ALL whitespaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.5, python-3.3

Basically, I'm trying to do a code in Python where a user inputs a sentence. However, I need my code to remove ALL whitespaces (e.g. tabs, space, index, etc.) and print it out.

This is what I have so far:

```
def output_without_whitespace(text):
  newText = text.split("")

print('String with no whitespaces: '.join(newText))
```

I'm clear that I'm doing a lot wrong here and I'm missing plenty, but, I haven't been able to thoroughly go over splitting and joining strings yet, so it'd be great if someone explained it to me.

This is the whole code that I have so far:

```
text = input(str('Enter a sentence: '))
print(f'You entered: {text}')

def get_num_of_characters(text):
 result = 0
 for char in text:
     result += 1
 return result
print('Number of characters: ', get_num_of_characters(text))

def output_without_whitespace(text):
    newtext = "".join(text.split())

print(f'String without whitespaces: {newtext}')
```

**I FIGURED OUT MY PROBLEM!**
I realize that in this line of code.

```
 print(f'String without whitespaces: {newtext}')
```

It's supposed to be.

```
print('String without whitespaces: ', output_without_whitespace(text))
```

I realize that my problem as to why the sentence without whitespaces was not printing back out to me was, because I was not calling out my function!

Comment: Don't forget to **call** your function.

Comment: @Austin, which function?

Comment: @eyllanesc "Duplicate" Question did not answer my question. It does not state how to print it out. And, I'm still getting errors within my code.

Comment: This function: `output_without_whitespace`. I don't see you calling it . :)

Comment: @Austin ah, I'm sorry I just edited my question. I just posted my full code.

Comment: @Vee You could show the code that you have tried with the solution of the other question, most of the answers in this post are similar to the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but here's how to implement it with `split` and `join`:

```
def output_without_whitespace(text):
  return ''.join(text.split())
```

so that:

```
output_without_whitespace(' this\t  is a\n test..\n ')
```

would return:

```
thisisatest..
```

Comment: I enter in this code, however, I'm still getting the same string WITH white spaces.

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code? There must be a typo when you entered the code. Please make sure you are not passing any argument to `split()`.

Comment: Yes, I did. Now, nothing is being printed out.

Comment: Oh, i figured out my problem

Comment: If you want it to print, you should just `print` it with `print(output_without_whitespace(' this\t  is a\n test..\n '))`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized my problem. I edited my question with the right code, fixing my problem haha

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this, but this seems the most obvious one to me. It is simple and efficient.

```
>>> with_spaces = '  The  quick brown       fox  '
>>> list_no_spaces = with_spaces.split() 
>>> ''.join(list_no_spaces)
'Thequickbrownfox'
```

`.split()` with no parameter splits a string  into a list wherever there's one or more white space characters, leaving out the white space...more details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

`''.join(list_no_spaces)` joins elements of the list into a string with nothing betwen the elements, which is what you want here: `'Thequickbrownfox'`.

If you had used `','.join(list_no_spaces)` you'd get `'The,quick,brown,fox'`.

Experienced Python programmers tend to use regular expressions sparingly. Often it's better to use tools like `.split()` and `.join()` to do the work, and keep regular expressions for where there is no alternative.

Comment: Did you even test this?

Comment: My bad-- writing to much Groovy these days. Fixed.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Explanation added. I wrote the original answer in a hurry on a phone, which is not a good look. I did actually write an explanation but somehow lost it on the StackOverflow app and had no time to rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution is to just use split and rejoin (similar to what you are doing):

```
def output_without_whitespace(text):
    return ''.join(text.split())
```

First we split the initial string to a list of words, then we join them all together.

So to think about it a bit:

```
text.split()
```

will give us a list of words (split by any whitespace). So for example:

```
'hello world'.split() -> ['hello', 'world']
```

And finally

```
''.join(<result of text.split()>)
```

joins all of the words in the given list to a single string. So:

```
''.join(['hello', 'world']) -> 'helloworld'
```

See [Remove all whitespace in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string-in-python) for more ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Get input, split, join

```
s = ''.join((input('Enter string: ').split()))
```

> ```
> Enter string: vash the stampede
> vashthestampede
> ```

Comment: I've already asked the user to input their sentence beforehand. How do I rewrite your suggested code without input?

Comment: `s = ''.join(variable_name.split())`

Comment: @Vee Same concept you apply `.split()` first then wrap that in `''.join()`