# Remove spaces only in URLs

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a file with a lot of text. Unfortunately, there are also some URLs with some spaces before or after the points. Example: `http://www .test27d .com/site1`

How can I replace these spaces such that only URLs are corrected (and not the other text, because sometimes, there has to be a space before or after a point ).

Comment: What is the correct URL here: `http://www.test27d` or `http://www.test27d.com/site1`? Both are valid.

Comment: It is impossible since there is no way to detect URLs if they have spaces in it... I think you should correct it by hand in a text editor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all whitespace in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @VinothRaja No, not all. Read the question.

Comment: How does other text looks like?

Comment: Depending on the text, looking at your example, maybe replacing a space followed by a dot may work: ie `text.replace(' .','.')` does it help?

Comment: @DSLima90: That will break sentences if the URLs are in written text.

Answer (score 2):

Find all the string matching the url criteria starting with `http` and then translate by removing spaces

```
import re
a='http://www .test27d .com/site1'
for i in re.findall('(^http://[\w\s\.\/]*)',a):
    print(i.translate(None,' '))
```

For testing

```
list_with_statements=['http://www .test27d .com/site1', 'string_with_no_spaces', 'string has spaces']
new_list=[]
for stat in list_with_statements:
    if re.search('(^http://[\w\s\.\/]*)',stat): # can also use str.startswith()
        stat=i.translate(None,' ')
    new_list.append(stat)
```

without regex

```
list_with_statements=['http://www .test27d .com/site1', 'string_with_no_spaces', 'string has spaces .']
new_list=[]
for stat in list_with_statements:
    if stat.startswith('http'):
        stat=i.translate(None,' ')
    new_list.append(stat)
print(new_list)
```

Outputs

```
['http://www.test27d.com/site1', 'string_with_no_spaces', 'string has spaces']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newstring = string.replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: Replace *only* in URLs. How do you recognize them?

Comment: Maybe with if 'www' in url and '.'.