# Delete line break in HTML file

Tags: python

I have an HTML file and I need to remove all line breaks between the body tag

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    </TITLE>
  </HEAD>
<BODY>
  <P></P>
  <P></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

to get it

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    </TITLE>
  </HEAD>
<BODY><P></P><P></P></BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270146/1287643) answer your question?

Comment: Did my solution solved your problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_content = open('name.html', 'r').read()

start_index, end_index = file_content.index("<BODY>"), file_content.index("</BODY>")
head , body_content, tail = file_content[:start_index], file_content[start_index:end_index], file_content[end_index:]

new_html = head + body_content.replace("\n", "") + tail
file_content = open('name.html', 'w')
file_content.write(new_html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the whole html into a string and do this.

```
bodystring = htmlstring[htmlstring.index('<BODY>'):htmlstring.index('</BODY>')+7]
htmlstring = htmlstring.replace(bodystring, bodystring.replace('\n',''))
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need, I need to remove  \n between the body tags using python

Comment: Probably 
`htmlstring.replace(bodystring, bodystring.replace(" ","").replace('\n',''))` this should work ,since @S1chewey need to remove all spaces in between body tags along with new line character

Answer (score 0):

This is a little homemade and uses no external libraries: (suppose your file is `foo.html`)

```py
with open('foo.html') as f:
    html_file = f.readlines()

body_index = []

for line in html_file :
    if 'BODY' in line :
        body_index.append(html_file.index(line))

start, end = body_index

start += 1

for i in range(start, end) :
    if '\n' in html_file[i] :
        html_file[i] = html_file[i].replace('\n', '')
```

done