# Code to remove extraneous spaces in a string in Python and keep 1 space between words

Tags: python

I want to write code that will remove extraneous spaces in a string. Any more than 1 space in between words would be an extraneous space. I want to remove those spaces but keep 1 space in between words

I've written code that will remove spaces at the beginning and the end but I'm not sure for to make it remove the middle spaces but keep 1 there.

```
#Space Cull
def space_cull(str):
  result = str 
  result = result.strip()
  return result
```

So this is what my code does right now

```
space_cull('    Cats   go   meow   ')
#It would return
'Cats   go   meow'
```

What I want it to do is this:

```
space_cull('    Cats   go    meow')
#It would return
'Cats go meow'
```

How should I do this?

Comment: `' '.join('    Cats   go   meow   '.split())`

Comment: Check this answer @KittyWhale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: Why is someone downvoting all answers??

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also idk why everyone is down voting all the answers they're very helpful.

Comment: @Nils, It's always a touchy subject on Stack to answer trivial questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions. IMO, They shouldn't be downvoted but I think it's best to do what Klaus did and just post the 1-liner trivial answer as a comment. People are free to answer whatever they want but they should know some people frown upon it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all whitespace in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: My guess is that some people think this question should be closed instead of being answered and are downvoting all answers to discourage people from answering questions like this or out of pettiness.

Comment: Well, thanks to that pettiness I got me a bronze badge. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Peter. That's not a duplicate. Retaining specific spaces is a simple, but absolutely not trivial modification at the beginner level

Comment: @MadPhysicist maybe the question isn't exactly the same, but the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270146/1084416) is comprehensive.

Comment: but this is different from that other question that some are recommending, that question is asking how to removed ALL spaces, I want to keep 1 space between the words instead of removing all space. Thank you all again though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works like this:

```
sentence = '    Cats   go   meow   '
" ".join(sentence.split())
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. You need a strip before or after, but seems like a reasonable approach

Comment: @MadPhysicist when executing my code I get the desired result. So there is no need to use an additional strip, or am I mistaken somehow?

Comment: Sure :D even though I want to note that I feel bad doing it.

Comment: I just had to add sentence = to the beginning so that It stored that data and then could return it, but it works great! (and i actually understand how it works lol)

Comment: If you work with strings regularly you should start looking into regex though. It is a library made for working with strings and is a lot more powerful than the built-in methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` to replace any number of spaces with a single space:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\s+", " ", "foo    bar")
"foo bar"
```

Comment: Though I would recommend using a `re.compile` if this is being done in a loop.

Comment: @PeterWood `\s+` grabs one or more spaces and then it replaces it with a single space.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse can you edit the answer to improve it?

Comment: The OP also seems to want to strip the input.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Well, yes, but they already know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
txt = '    Cats   go   meow   '

def space_cull(string):

    word = string.split(" ")
    result = ""
    for elem in word:
        if not elem == '':
            result += str(elem) + ' '
    return result.strip()

print(space_cull(txt))
```

output:

```
Cats go meow
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use built-in string methods:

```
x = "  cats    go    meow     "
print(*x.strip().split())
```

Output will be:

```
cats go meow
```

Comment: Why do that when you can just do `print(*x.split())` for the same print statement? And in any case, that just prints the value as output, when the value under the hood is still a list. If OP wants to return a string without extra spaces (not a list), then your solution would need a ' '.join(...) to be complete.