# Printing every other letters of a string without the spaces on Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to build a function that will take a string and print every other letter of the string, but it has to be without the spaces.

For example:

```
def PrintString(string1):
    for i in range(0, len(string1)):
        if i%2==0:
            print(string1[i], sep="")

PrintString('My Name is Sumit')
```

It shows the output:

```
M
 
a
e
i
 
u
i
```

But I don't want the spaces. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear whether you do not want the spaces in the output or you just want to ignore the spaces before picking every other character.

Comment: I don't want the spaces in the output

Comment: then just update the condition in the `if` to reflect what you do not want to print, e.g. `if i % 2 == 0 and string1[i] != ' ':`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all whitespace in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string)

Comment: `sep=""` does nothing in your code. Did you mean `end=""`?

Answer (score 1):

Use stepsize `string1[::2]` to iterate over every 2nd character from string and ignore if it is `" "`

```
def PrintString(string1):
    print("".join([i for i in string1[::2] if i!=" "]))

PrintString('My Name is Sumit')
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the spaces before you do the loop.

And there's no need to test `i%2` in the loop. Use a slice that returns every other character.

```
def PrintString(string1):
    string1 = string1.replace(' ', '')
    print(string1[::2])
```

Comment: The same as mine but also the best!

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the spaces and get every other letter

```
def PrintString(string1):
  return print(string1.replace(" ", "") [::2])

PrintString('My Name is Sumit')
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to first remove the spaces and then pick every second letter or take every second letter and print it, unless it is a space:

```
s = "My name is Summit"
print(s.replace(" ", "")[::2])
print(''.join([ch for ch in s[::2] if ch != " "]))
```

Prints:

```
MnmiSmi
Maeiumt
```

Answer (score -1):

You could alway create a quick function for it where you just simply replace the spaces with an empty string instead.
Example

```
def remove(string): 
    return string.replace(" ", "")
```

There's a lot of different approaches to this problem. This thread explains it pretty well in my opinion: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-spaces-from-a-string/

Comment: This doesn't print every other character, it prints every character that isn't a space.