# Remove duplicate spaces from string except new line character (\n) in Python

Tags: python

I have a string and I want to remove duplicate spaces from that. But my string has a new line character `\n` and after doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270146/14362977), this character also is deleted.
Output of this:

```
s = 'A B     C  D \n EF   G'
print(s)
s = " ".join(s.split())
print(s)
```

is as follows:

```
A B     C  D 
 EF   G
------------
A B C D EF G
```

But I do not want to remove this character. The desired output:

```
A B C D
 EF G
```

Comment: You could just split on newlines first and re-join in two stages: `'\n'.join([' '.join(line.split()) for line in s.split('\n')])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pattern to match 2 or more whitespace chars without the newline, and in the replacement use a single space.

```
[^\S\r\n]{2,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9vPhBz/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZuWDwW)

For example

```
import re

s = 'A B     C  D \n EF   G'
print(re.sub(r"[^\S\r\n]{2,}", " ", s))
```

Output

```
A B C D 
 EF G
```

Answer (score 0):

use filter.

```
a='A B     C  D \n EF   G'
b=" ".join(list(filter(None,a.split(" "))))
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex.

Split the string by `'\n'` and then combine multiple whitespace into 1 whitespace.

```
import re
comb_whitespace = re.compile(r"\s+")
for i in s.split('\n'):
    print(comb_whitespace.sub(" ", i))
```

---

```
A B C D 
 EF G
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s need to add \n split

```
s = 'A B     C  D \n EF   G'
print(s)
s = " ".join(s.split())
s = " ".join(s.split('\n'))
print(s)
```

Outs

```
A B     C  D 
 EF   G
A B C D EF G
```

Comment: Read the desired output of question again.