# How to output a sentence or phrase with no whitespace?

Tags: python, whitespace, removing-whitespace

This is an assignment where we have to take a sentence or phrase as input and output the phrase without whitespace.

Example: if input is 'hello there'
output would be 'hellothere'

the code I have so far only outputs the string in separate letters: Like 'h', 'e', 'l', etc etc

```
def output_without_whitespace(input_str):
   lst = []
   for char in input_str:
       if char != ' ':
           lst.append(char)
   return lst

if __name__ == '__main__':
   phrase = str(input('Enter a sentence or phrase:\n'))
   print(output_without_whitespace(phrase))
```

Comment: `return input_str.replace(' ', '')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all whitespace in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string)

Comment: You do not need a loop, just do ``input_str.replace(' ','')``

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. You just need to join the list into a string.

```
print(''.join(output_without_whitespace(phrase)))
```

You could replace the loop in your function with a list comprehension.

```
def output_without_whitespace(input_str):
   return [ch for ch in input_str if ch != ' ']
```

That will return the same list your implementation does.

If you want your function to return a string, we can use the same `join` from before:

```
def output_without_whitespace(input_str):
   return ' '.join([ch for ch in input_str if ch != ' '])
```

But if we're doing that, we don't really need to pass a list to `join`. Instead we can use a generator expression.

```
def output_without_whitespace(input_str):
   return ' '.join(ch for ch in input_str if ch != ' ')
```

As others have pointed out, all of this is overkill if we just use `replace`.

```
def output_without_whitespace(input_str):
   return input_str.replace(' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def output_without_whitespace(input_str):
   str1=input_str.replace(" ","")
   return str1
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
   phrase = str(input('Enter a sentence or phrase:\n'))
   print(output_without_whitespace(phrase))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def output_without_whitespace(phrase):
    return phrase.replace(" ", "")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    phrase = str(input('Enter a sentence or phrase:\n'))
    print(output_without_whitespace(phrase))
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270146/17190006

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).