# How to check for spaces before or after a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How can I find if there are spaces placed before the continuous string I have? For example:     `1a2f3adfs3j`  With this string I want to identify if there are spaces before and after it, then remove them.

Comment: `str.strip` might be what you want.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string

Comment: That is a valid way to remove them, but I want to identify if they are there, and only strip the ones after visible characters.

Comment: you can use pythons inbuilt string class specific `string.startswith()` and `string.endswith()` functions that return booloean

Comment: `if mystring.startswith(' ') or mystring.endswith(' ')`

Comment: Alright it seems to work, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to check if they are there? `strip` will only remove leading and trailing spaces. If they are not there - nothing will happen...

Answer (score 3):

If you actually have interest in detecting the presence of these spaces you can check by taking advantage of the ability to slice strings.

```py
s = " abc "
assert(s[0] == " ") # first char
assert(s[-1] == " ") # last char
```

But there are other ways:

```py
assert(s.startswith(" "))
assert(s.endswith(" "))
# or
first, *_, last = s
assert(first == " ")
assert(last == " ")
```

You could also check both at the same time:

```py
assert(s[::len(s)-1] == "  ")
# or
assert(s[0] + s[-1] == "  ")
```

Otherwise, as others pointed out. [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is likely what you're after. It will remove leading and trailing whitespace, but leave any within the text.

Comment: as a small second question relating to this but not enough to make a post, how can I remove the spaces outside the text, but keep the ones inside the characters? Sorry

Comment: I'm happy to help further, but I don't understand your question? If you mean remove the spaces preceding non-whitespace characters and spaces following the last non-whitespace character, `strip` is the way to go. If you mean something else, let me know.

Comment: For example `assert(" a b ".strip() == "a b")`. Notice it left the space that was neither leading nor trailing.

Answer (score 1):

To actually see if you have spaces, you could use:

```
s = " abcd1234 "
print(s[0] == " ", s[-1] == " ")
```

Or another way is to see if it `startswith` or `endswith` a space:

```
print(s.startswith(" "), s.endswith(" "))
```

To remove the spaces:

```
s = s.strip()
```

should do and remove the spaces and assign it to `s`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var = "   abc   "

var.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
>>> var = ' 1a2f3adfs3j '
>>> var == f' {var[1:-1]} '
True
```

which approach is not space-specific. e.g

```
>>> var = '__1a2f3adfs3j__'
>>> var == f'__{var[2:-2]}__'
True
```